# Problemas con variables C#

Tags: c#, variables

Quisiera saber si es posible actualizar o refrescar (o algo asi) a una variable, sin asignarle nuevos valores.
Por ejemplo.
Declaro un vector y le doy valores, luego declaro una variable. N contiene una formula.
vector [0] = 2;
vector [1] = 10;
N = vector [i] * 10;
En determinado momento yo quiero que
i = 1;
Fx = N;
y quiero que el valor que tiene N se actualice antes de almacenarse.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

No existe como tal lo que pides, pero puedes tener propiedades que regresen el valor computado.

---

**Opción 1**

Se me ocurre que puedes tener una clase genérica que reciba una función como fórmula:

```
public class Formula<TResult>
{
    public Formula(Func<TResult> formula)
    {
        Value = formula;
    }

    // cada vez que invoques a la propiedad Value, se ejecuta la función 
    // que pasaste por parámetro a la clase
    public TResult Value { get; }
}
```

Y para usarla:

```
int value = 5; // el valor original
// en este caso, el '<int>' en el constructor le dice de que tipo es el valor que regresa la fórmula
var N = new Formula<int>(() => value * 10); 
var result1 = N.Value; // result1 = 50
value = 10;
var result2 = N.Value; // result2 = 100
```

Si quieres evitar el poner el tipo de dato del resultado de la fórmula, es decir, quitar el " < int > " en " new Formula< int > ", puedes crear una clase estática con un método tipo factory:

```
public static class Formula
{
    public static Formula<TResult> From<TResult>(Func<TResult> formula)
    {
        return new Formula<TResult>(formula);
    }   
}
```

Y así no tienes que escribir el tipo de dato del resultado de la fórmula ya que el compilador lo va a inferir:

```
int value = 5;
var N = Formula.From(() => value * 10);
var result1 = N.Value; // result1 = 50
value = 10;
var result2 = N.Value; // result2 = 100
```

Si tu fórmula es mas compleja, tienes dos opciones:

```
var N = Formula.From(() => {
    int result;

    // aquí irían todas las líneas de código 
    // para calcular el resultado

    return result;
});
```

ó:

```
var N = Formula.From(Metodo);
.
.
.
.
private int Metodo()
{
    int result;

    // aquí irían todas las líneas de código 
    // para calcular el resultado

    return result;
}
```

---

**Opción 2**

Si lo que quieres son vectores, puedes tener una clase que reciba un vector y una fórmula, ejemplo;

```
public class Formula<T, TResult>
{
    readonly T[] vector;
    readonly Func<T, TResult> formula;

    public Formula(T[] vector, Func<T, TResult> formula)
    {
        this.vector = vector;
        this.formula = formula;
    }

    public TResult this[int index] => formula(vector[index]);
}
```

Y para usarla:

```
var vector = new[] { 2, 10 };
var N = new Formula<int, int>(vector, i => i * 10);

var value1 = N[0]; // value1 = 20
var value2 = N[1]; // value2 = 100

vector[0] = 4;
vector[1] = 20;

var value3 = N[0]; // value3 = 10
var value4 = N[1]; // value4 = 200
```

Y como en la primer clase, puedes crear una clase estática con un método estático tipo factory, voy a reutilizar la anterior:

```
public static class Formula
{
    // método tipo factory ya creado anteriormente
    public static Formula<TResult> From<TResult>(Func<TResult> formula)
    {
        return new Formula<TResult>(formula);
    }   

    // método factory para la clase Formula de vectores:
    public static Formula<T, TResult> From<T, TResult>(T[] vector, Func<T, TResult> formula)
    {
        return new Formula<T, TResult>(vector, formula);
    }
}
```

Por último, con esas clases, el valor que regresa la "fórmula" no necesariamente tiene que ser el mismo tipo que el valor del dato original, un ejemplo:

```
int meses = 1;
var N = Formula.From(() => DateTime.Today.AddMonths(meses));
var mesSiguiente = N.Value; // mesSiguiente  = la fecha un mes adelante
meses = 5;
var enCincoMeses = N.Value; // enCincoMeses = la fecha 5 meses adelante
```

Comment: no es mas facil si solamente creamos una propiedad "get" ?

Comment: @Mike bueno, te ahorras solo una línea, si te refieres a public TResult Value => formula(); Lo cambiaré para que se refleje la diferencia.